# Searchable exposed filters on views

Tags: views, javascript, input-formats

I have an exposed filter of a taxonomy vocabulary (localities) and I want the user to be able to search on it in order to find the desired values more easily.

I am using [BEF](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) at the moment. I found the [jquery ui multiselect widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_multiselect_widget) but it does not seem to work with views filters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer.

I also faced same kind of issue and I followed the below url  and its worked for me

http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-views-autocomplete-filter

Comment: Did you use it for taxonomy field?I tried unsuccessfully to use it on select list filter and taxonomy filter. It seems to work just for text fields unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen

it works as well for taxonomies with multiple selection values.

Hope this helps someone.